# iOS - UILabel editing, overlaying an image?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilabel

As you can probably tell from my last few questions, I am working on a screen that allows users to edit labels. Pages and all the other lovely apps have glorious resizing handles to show what label is currently being edited.

I am trying to get some feedback on the best way to do this. Is it possible to add an 'dot' image to the centre of all the edges of the label? Is it possible to change the background colour only in sections of a label?
Or should I add an image on top of the label and disable it? The most important feature is for  only the uilabel to respond to touches. If I overlay an image, I want it to ignore the touch and hand it off to the label.

Any feedback appreciated!
Cheers Guys!

Comment: My suggestion is to break this down into individual tasks. For example, start by trying to get editing implemented, and when you run into a problem post a question about your specific problem. The way your question is now it is just too broad and it seems like you have not even tried to write anything yet.

Comment: Editing is done, I only require the aesthetics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find as many opinions on this as there are programmers. There is not built-in decoration for a view that shows the dot in the middle of each side. But you can add that easily enough. One way is instantiate four instances of an image with the dot and add them as subviews of the view you are decorating. you can then set the center of each dot on the center of each edge in the parent view. As long as clipping is turned off in the parent view, these will show up (if they are not `hidden`) even if they extend outside the frame of the parent view.

I don't understand what you want to accomplish by changing the background color in sections of the label view, but I this probably has some moderate complexity to it.

You can also to this with core graphics. I'll stop there, though. There are literally many ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I figured the best way was to use images, will give it a cheeky go today and see what happens.